# Control focus order between ViewGroups with uncertain items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, pagerslidingtabstrip, android-tv

I have an Android TV layout likes the image below.

1. A PagerSlidingTabStrip on the top, and the data are pulled from the server;
2. A ViewPager with Fragments on the bottom, and each fragment has a horizontal RecyclerView.

**Scenario:**

When the first tab(**tab0**) gets focus, then press the D-pad in **down->right** direction, the **item2** in the RecyclerView get focus which works as expected;

Then press the D-pad in **up** direction, the **tab4** get focus, which follows the default focus search order.

**Question:**

My question is how to keep the **tab0** (last focused tab) get focus instead of tab4.

I know we can define the behavior by specifying, for each View, which control should gain focus next with *nextFocusUp, nextFocusUp, nextFocusLeft, nextFocusRight* attributes. But how to control focus order between ViewGroup with uncertain items for my part.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem finally, described as below:

1. Keep a reference of last focused view in `PagerSlidingTabStrip`;
2. Create a custom `ViewGroup`, which is the parent view of `PagerSlidingTabStrip` and `ViewPager`;
3. Override the `dispatchKeyEvent` method in the `ViewGroup` :

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
       if (shouldInterceptDownKeyEvent(event) || shouldInterceptUpKeyEvent(event)) {
           if (mTabs.getLastFocusedView() != null) {
               mTabs.getLastFocusedView().requestFocus();
           }
           return true;
       }
       return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
   }
   ```

Comment: I wonder if you could instead implement a custom `focusSearch` on your ViewGroup?